# When I add an element to a linked list contained in an array of linked lists why every other element of the list gets deleted?

Tags: c, arrays, list, singly-linked-list

*UPDATED*

The problem of this code is that after the matrix has been transformed into an array of linked lists, it looks like no value is contained in the array of linked lists.
I think the problem is in the function that add a node to a specific list of the array of linked lists.

```
// node
struct node {
    int n;
    struct node* next_ptr;
};

// prototypes
void fill_mat(int mat[][SIZE]);
void mat_to_list(int mat[][SIZE]);
void insertSortedLinkedList(struct node *l, int value);
void print_mat(int mat[][SIZE]);
void print_vet();

// array of pointers
struct node* vet[SIZE];
int visitato[SIZE];

// main function
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int mat[SIZE][SIZE];
    int i, j;

    // reset the matrix
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // generate graph with weights
    srand(time(NULL));
    fill_mat(mat);

    // transform matrix in an array of linked lists
    mat_to_list(mat);
    print_mat(mat);
    printf("\n");
    print_vet();

    return 0;
}


// generate graph
void fill_mat(int mat[][SIZE]) {
    int x, y, z;

    for(x = 0; x < (SIZE * SIZE) / 2;) {
        y = rand() % SIZE;
        z = rand() % SIZE;

        if(mat[y][z] == 0) {
            mat[y][z] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            ++x;
        }
    }
}

// insert in list
void addNode(struct node **st, int d) {
    struct node *temp = *st;

    if(temp == NULL) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    } else {
        while((temp)->next_ptr != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next_ptr;
        }

        temp->next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp = temp->next_ptr;
    }

    temp->n = d; // this must done using strncpy
    temp->next_ptr = NULL;
}

// transform matrix to array of linked lists
void mat_to_list(int mat[][SIZE]) {
    int i, j;

    // reset array
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        vet[i] = NULL;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {

        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            if(mat[i][j] != 0) {
                    addNode(&(vet[i]), mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// print matrix
void print_mat(int mat[][SIZE]) {
    int i, j
    ;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            printf("%-2d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// print array of linked lists
void print_vet() {
    int i;
    struct node* temp;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("ARRAY CELL: %d\n", i);
        temp = vet[i];

        while(temp != NULL) {
            printf("NODE VALUE --> ");
            printf("%d\n", temp->n);
            temp = temp->next_ptr;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `*st = (*st)->next_ptr` You are modifying the original pointer. You need to use a tmp variable for list traversal.

Comment: can you write the code for the temp variable?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and see [ask].

Comment: Yes I can. But how about you think about it and give it a try since you now know where the problem is?

Comment: I added a temp variable but it still modify the whole thing

Comment: Well, then show that code and ask about that so we can point out your problem. And please always provide a [MCVE] so that we don't waste time asking for missing info.

Comment: Why not `struct node *tmp = *st;`?

Comment: It doesn't print anything now

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] (read the link). I'd like to answer the question but to do so I need to write out the fix and test it to ensure it works. But I'm not going to bother to do that if you don't provide an MCVE as I don't want to spend the time constructing the rest of the code needed to compile and run the test.

Comment: I updated the answer with a more complete and verifiable version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not understood where there is an array of lists and how long you are going to show your editions of the function. But in any case a correct function can look the following way

```
void addNode( struct node **st, int d ) 
{
    while ( *st ) st = &( *st )->next_ptr;

    *st = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    ( *st )->n = d;
    ( *st )->next_ptr = NULL;
}
```

Or the following way

```
int addNode( struct node **st, int d ) 
{
    while ( *st ) st = &( *st )->next_ptr;

    *st = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    int success = *st != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        ( *st )->n = d;
        ( *st )->next_ptr = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you and sorry for the lack of clarity in my question, I tried to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are modifying the original pointer.
An iterator can be used to find the last node.

In your calling function, you can create an iterator.

```
 first = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
 iterator = first;
```

In your function, you can pass the iterator

```
void addNode(node *iterator, int d) {
    /*Create a new node*/
    newNode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->n = d;
    newNode->next_ptr = NULL;

    /*Iterate through your list to find end*/
    if (iterator != 0) {
        while (iterator->next != 0) {
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
    }
    /*Add item to last link in list*/
    iterator->next = newNode;
}
```